# Defined virtual functions cause type_info dependence

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, abi

I have the following file `foobar.cc`:

```
struct Foo
{
  virtual int do_something() const = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
  virtual int do_something() const override
  { return 1; }
};

Bar bar;
```

When I try to build a shared object out of it like so:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC foobar.cc -o foobar.so
```

`nm foobar.so` outputs the lines:

```
U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
```

But why? Shouldn't this only be the case if one of the virtual functions was not either pure or did not have a definition? I know I can circumvent this by compiling with `fno-rtti` but I'm trying to understand this behaviour.

Comment: `Foo *fp = new Bar; Bar *bp = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(fp);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see some dependencies on these libstdc++ symbols whenever:

- A constructor is odr-used for a dynamic class type (has a virtual function or virtual base).
- Any `typeid` expression whose operand is a class type or an expression of class type is compiled (so not in a `decltype`, in an inline function never used, etc.)
- Any `throw` expression with an operand of class type is compiled.

Note the latter two don't require a dynamic class type at all. Their equivalents for other types also cause dependencies on other libstdc++ `type_info`-related symbols.

This is a consequence of the way `type_info` inheritance information is stored, following the [Itanium ABI (section 2.9.4 RTTI Layout)](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#rtti). The `type_info` object for any class type actually has most-derived type `__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info` or `__cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info`, which inherit `std::type_info`. But since `std::type_info` is dynamic, so are `__class_type_info` and `__si_class_type_info`. This means the created objects of those type must have vptrs. Those vptrs must include a pointer to the `std::type_info` objects representing the implementation types `__class_type_info` and `__si_class_type_info` themselves. Apparently those objects are created without linkage on demand, but each contains a pointer to the name strings to be returned by `std::type_info::name()`, which are the actual "`_ZTVN`" symbols you see linked from libstdc++.